# Django model for a Postgres view

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-migrations

**Edit:** There seems to be some confusion about what I'm asking. That model is for the [Postgres view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createview.html) that I created in migration 0009. I was under the impression that Django won't generate a migration for a model if it has the `managed = False` option. However, it's still trying to create it.

Also, I'm using Django 1.8 with Python 3.4.

I'm having trouble creating a Django model for a Postgres view, using these links as a guide: [drdaeman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1281051/2258441) and [eceppda's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29532034/2258441) answer in [Can I use a database view as a model in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507795/can-i-use-a-database-view-as-a-model-in-django). I also looked up the Options.managed entry in [Django's API docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.managed). However, even with this, it's creating a migration that adds a table for the view's model.

This is my code so far:

#### foo/models.py

```
class RelevantModel(models.Model):
    rebate_pool_total = models.OneToOneField('foo.VirtualTotal', null=True)
    total = models.DecimalField(null=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=32)

class VirtualTotal(models.Model):
    relevant_model = models.ForeignKey('foo.RelevantModel')
    total = models.DecimalField(null=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=32)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

#### foo/migrations/0009_add_foo_view.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('foo', '0008_previous_migration'),
    ]

    sql = """
    create VIEW foo_virtualtotal AS
      SELECT rest of view...
    """

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL('DROP VIEW IF EXISTS foo_virtualtotal;'),
        migrations.RunSQL(sql)
    ]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's no migration here that creates a table as you have described. This migration shows custom code that you have put in there

Comment: I know. When I generate migrations for that app after that, it's still trying to create a table for the VirtualTotal model. I was under the impression that `managed = False` tells Django to not generate migrations for that table.

Comment: what makes you say that?

Comment: That's how I interpreted the API documentation on `Options.managed`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#managed. Am I misinterpreting it? I first read about it in this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507795/can-i-use-a-database-view-as-a-model-in-django/1281051#1281051.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Django does create a migration for each newly added table in your app regardless of whether it's a managed model or not. However there is a very important and subtle difference when you use the `managed=False` setting. The resultant migration is a dummy entry. It does not execute any SQL at all.

To confirm this add a new model that is unmanaged

```
class Dummy(models.Model):
    something = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
       managed = False
```

now when you do `makemigrations` followed by `sqlimigrate *myapp* *migration_number*` you will see that it doesn't produce any sql.

If on the other hand, you do find that Django is trying to create a table for you, that usually means that you had the same model in existence earlier but at the time the model was managed. To confirm this, search your `migrations` folder for `VirtualTotal` which is the name of the model in question.