# Django Model - Modeling on Django ORM (Postgres-12 Database View)

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to model Postgres database view (I'm using Postgres 12) to Django ORM  (Django 3.1 and Python 3.8.5). I tried this answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38110785/django-model-for-a-postgres-view) in stackoverflow but still I got the same error.

To visualized my database schema

```
Database Objects
Tables:
|_items
|_uom
|_location
|
Views:
|_vItems
```

the `vItems` contains the SQL command joining the three tables `items, uom, location`, when running the SQL command below to the `pgAdmin 4`. I can fetch all the items data without getting any errors.

```
SELECT * FROM vItems
```

Here is my Django `models.py` code:

```
class Items(models.Model):
    id          = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    item_code   = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    sku         = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    name        = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    uom_id      = models.IntegerField()
    location_id = models.IntegerField()
    created_date= models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created_by  = models.IntegerField()
    updated_date= models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    updated_by  = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "items"


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('item_detail', kwargs = {'pk': self.id})


class UOM(models.Model):
    id          = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    uom         = models.CharField(max_length = 50) 
    created_date= models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created_by  = models.IntegerField()
    updated_date= models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    updated_by  = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "uom"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.uom


class Location(models.Model):
    id          = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    location    = models.CharField(max_length = 50) 
    created_date= models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created_by  = models.IntegerField()
    updated_date= models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    updated_by  = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "location"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.location


class vItems(models.Model):
    id          = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    item_code   = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    sku         = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    name        = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    uom_id      = models.IntegerField()
    location_id = models.IntegerField()
    uom         = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    location    = models.CharField(max_length = 50) 
    created_date= models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created_by  = models.IntegerField()
    updated_date= models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    updated_by  = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "vItems"
```

Here is my error to `Django`

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/items/

Django Version: 3.1
Python Version: 3.8.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'items.apps.ItemsConfig',
 'users.apps.UsersConfig',
 'dashboard.apps.DashboardConfig',
 'crispy_forms']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template D:\DELETE THIS\PiTON\web\fnd\src\templates\index.html, error at line 35
   relation "vItems" does not exist
LINE 1: ...Items"."updated_date", "vItems"."updated_by" FROM "vItems" O...

*some python stack tracing here...*

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /items/
Exception Value: relation "vItems" does not exist
LINE 1: ...Items"."updated_date", "vItems"."updated_by" FROM "vItems" O...
                                                             ^
```

**EDIT: Additional Information**
Here is the `0003_vItems.py` file under `migrations`:

The commented `operations = [...]` block of code was the original `makemigrations items` for my `vItems` model. And the uncommented code below is the solution I've tried but still I'm getting the same error.

```
# Generated by Django 3.1 on 2020-09-19 09:30

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.utils.timezone


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('items', '0002_location_uom'),
    ]

    # operations = [
    #     migrations.CreateModel(
    #         name='vItems',
    #         fields=[
    #             ('id', models.AutoField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
    #             ('item_code', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
    #             ('sku', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
    #             ('name', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
    #             ('description', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
    #             ('uom_id', models.IntegerField()),
    #             ('location_id', models.IntegerField()),
    #             ('uom', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
    #             ('location', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
    #             ('created_date', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)),
    #             ('created_by', models.IntegerField()),
    #             ('updated_date', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)),
    #             ('updated_by', models.IntegerField()),
    #         ],
    #         options={
    #             'db_table': 'vItems',
    #             'managed': False,
    #         },
    #     ),
    # ]

    sql = """
        CREATE VIEW vItems
        AS
        SELECT it.id,
            it.item_code,
            it.sku,
            it.name,
            it.description,
            it.uom_id,
            it.location_id,
            it.created_date,
            it.created_by,
            it.updated_date,
            it.updated_by,
            uom.uom,
            loc.location
        FROM 
            items it
            JOIN uom uom ON uom.id = it.uom_id
            JOIN location loc ON loc.id = it.location_id;
    """

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL('DROP VIEW IF EXISTS vItems;'),
        migrations.RunSQL(sql)
    ]
```

And here is the `views.py` that calls the `vItems` from the `models.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import (
    LoginRequiredMixin,     # CLASS BASED REQUIRED LOGIN TO GAIN ACCESS
    UserPassesTestMixin     # UPDATE ONLY IF DATA IS FROM THE CURRENT USER [CAN BE USE SUPERVISOR UPDATE ONLY]
)
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView, 
    DetailView,
    CreateView,
    UpdateView,
    DeleteView
)


from .models import (
    Items,
    UOM,
    Location,
    vItems
)


class ItemListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = vItems
    template_name = 'items/list.html' # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'items'
    ordering = ['name']

**some class based views code here...**
```

To summarize this question base on my own understanding, I'm getting an error from Django as if there is something wrong in my `models.py (class vItems)` that cannot be translated by `Django` to native SQL command, something that is related to `"relation"` stated above on error, I'm guessing the the `INNER JOIN` statement? But it doesn't make sense to me because the SQL command is perfectly working on `pgAdmin 4`

What am I missing here to get this error?

Thank you in advance for the answers.

Comment: Can you post your vItems model's migration file also?

Comment: I have added the `vItems` model's migration file. I forgot to add it when drafting my question. I hope this information can help to elaborate the question. thanks

Comment: Are you still getting this same error or different? Exception Value: relation "vItems" does not exist LINE 1: ...Items"."updated_date", "vItems"."updated_by" FROM "vItems" O...

Comment: @AyushBansal Yes, I tried to use the `items` table pass it on my view. I can get the items data. when I call and use the `vItems` I'm getting the same error stated above.

Comment: If you are still getting the same error even after commenting the operations part of vItems migration then it means you still have this vItems CreateModel operations in some other migration file.Do check it once.

Comment: @AyushBansal I have checked all the migrations files, only the `0003_vitems.py` file contains the `CreateModel operations`. It's really strange .