# How to Map table views of a legacy Database in Oracle to django models?

Tags: django, oracle, django-models, orm, inspectdb

I am working on a project that requires connecting to an existing remote Oracle database. the problem is that the client has not given full access to the database. instead i'm only given accesss to some views(Relational Database View) of the database. the table names are not provided.

I'm able to perfrom raw sql queries to the legacydb in my django view.
But it would be very much more easier if i could generate the models for these views and use django ORM. is there any way to accomplish this? What I'm expecting is to use some commands like inspectdb to generate the models from the view provided by the oracle legacy database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use a database view as a model in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507795/can-i-use-a-database-view-as-a-model-in-django)

Comment: @NafeesAnwar thanks, but not what i'm looking for. I'm trying to generate the models and use ORM for the legacy database